# On integrals related to $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: calculus, integration

You are given the result that $$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$

a. Use this result to find $$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-ax^2} dx$$
b. Use the above results to find $$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} x^2e^{-ax^2} dx$$
[Hint: Consider $\frac{d}{d\alpha} \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx$]

c. Use the above results to to show that $$P(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}} \exp \left( -\frac{x^2}{4Dt}\right) $$ is a normalized distribution.

*(Note: I'm still learning - this problem is somewhat advanced for my level, so if someone could write out an explicit and complete solution, that would be the most helpful answer for me.)*

***As of now, @matt has successfully helped me to understand the solutions for (a) and (b) in his response below; but I still need to have the solution for (c) explained to me.  I do not understand what needs to be done. for (c).***

Comment: I believe first integral should be: $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \mathbf{\sqrt{\pi}}$ not $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo Yes, you and matt are both correct - the typo has been corrected.  (And yes, this is a homework problem.)

Comment: @Davide Giraudo  What substitution am I supposed to be using?

Comment: To add to Davide Giraudo's excellent suggestion about integrating by parts for the second question, you should first write down the _derivative_ of $e^{-ax^2}$ which will help you in writing the integrand in the form $u\,dv$ that is needed for integration by parts: you want $dv$ to be something whose antiderivative $v$ is known to you.

Comment: I hope you have looked at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a. We make the substitution $t=\sqrt{a}x$, $a>0$, thus:
 $$
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx
  =\lim_{\substack{n\rightarrow\infty\\m\rightarrow\infty}}\int_{-n}^{+m}e^{-ax^2}dx
  =\lim_{\substack{n\rightarrow\infty\\m\rightarrow\infty}}\int_{-n\sqrt{a}}^{+m\sqrt{a}}e^{-t^2}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{a}}
  =\frac1{\sqrt{a}}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} dx
  = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
 $$

b. We differentiating our result from part (a) with respect to $a$.
 $$
  \frac{d}{da} \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx
  = \frac{d}{da}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\right)
  \quad\Rightarrow\quad
  \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{d}{da}e^{-ax^2}dx
  = \frac{d}{da}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\right)
 $$

Note that moving $\frac{d}{da}$ inside the integral is justified since both $e^{-ax^2}$ and $\frac{d}{da}(e^{-ax^2})$ are continuous.

Simplifying gives:
 $$
 -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2e^{-ax^2}dx = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a^{3/2}}
  \quad\Rightarrow\quad
 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2e^{-ax^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a^{3/2}}
 $$

c. We must show: (1) $P(x,t)$ is non-negative; and (2) $\int P(x,t)=1$. We establish (1) by noting that $\exp(-x^2/4DT)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  To establish (2), observe the following result which follows from part (a) (we set $a=1/(4Dt)$):
 $$
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}P(x,t)\;dx
  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \exp \left( -\frac{x^2}{4Dt}\right)\;dx
  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1/(4Dt)}} = 1
 $$

EDIT: Added some clarification for part (c).

Comment: Thank you, I have finally caught up with your solutions for (a.) and (b.) but I'm still trying to understand what is happening in your solution for (c.)  I don't understand what we need to do to show that the function P(x,t) is a normalised distribution.  If you or anyone can offer me some walkthrough commentary, that would be most helpful...

Comment: I would say that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}} \exp \left( -\frac{x^2}{4Dt}\right)$ is a *probability distribution* in that it is non-negative and its integral is $1$. matt has shown the second point, and the first is obvious. *normalized* is a slightly confusing word here, with more than one obvious meaning.

Comment: @Srivatsan can you identify the said typo please?

Comment: @ptrcao Oops, sorry. On closer look, there's no typo.  I thought that the denominator said $4Dt$ instead of $1/(4Dt)$. The post is correct. Can you tell us what you need help with in (c.)? (I removed my previous comment. Apologies to matt.)

Comment: @Henry can you link me to an authoritative source that defines/characterises a probability distribution as you have described it - a function which is non-negative and equal to $1$ when integrated?

Comment: @Srivatsan I don't understand what matt is doing.  I see that he is multiplying the integrals of the two terms comprising the function $P(x,t)$, but why has he done this?  Also, there is no $dx$ or $dt$ specified in the integrals; why is this?

Comment: @ptrcao I unintentionally left out the dx. Thank you for letting me know I have edited appropriately. I agree with Henry on his definition. Wikipedia has the following definition for normalising constant: "A normalizing constant is a constant by which an everywhere non-negative function must be multiplied so the area under its graph is 1" (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizing_constant). In the context of (c) the normalizing constant is 1/(4Dt).

Comment: @ptcao: [Planet Math](http://planetmath.org/?method=png&from=objects&id=2884&op=getobj) has the formal measure-theoretic definition.

Comment: @Henry: Thanks - the first criterion specified by [Planet Math](http://planetmath.org/?method=png&from=objects&id=2884&op=getobj), that the function must be "$\mu$-measurable" - can you explain what this means?

Comment: @ptcao: Not briefly in measure theory terms.  You might like to think of it as an integrable function.

Comment: @Henry In that case, what does $\mu$ refer to exactly?

Comment: @ptrcao: it is the measure for the space: on the real line the measure of the interval $[a,b]$ is usually the length, i.e. $b-a$.

Comment: @ptrcao: I have edited my original post adding further details on part (c).

Comment: @matt thank you for the clarification - it was most helpful.

Comment: @ptrcao: Glad to be of assistance :)